# How to override addObserver method in Objective c?

Tags: objective-c

How can I override the addObserver() method in objective C?
I tried doing this? But I get a compiler error saying 'Parse Issue xpected expression'

```
- (void)addObserver:(NSObject *)observer
         forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
            options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptions)options
            context:(void *)context
{

    [super addObserver:observer forKeyPath:keyPath options:options context:context];
}
```

Comment: are all the `#`, `<`, and `>` characters actually in your code or is that a transcription error?

Comment: Why don't you pass valid values to method when called on `super`?

Comment: I remove all my changes just to get calling the super addObserver() method to compile.

Comment: You can only call `super xxx` if the a parent class actually implements `xxx`. The `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` method is from a protocol. So unless one of the parent classes happens to conform to the protocol and implement the method, you can't call `super`.

Comment: An alternative is to wrap calls to this in your own method. Not override but wrap with a different method signature. A prefix would work.